# Drop last query in client side

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown who populate depending of selected radio button:

**JS**

```
 $(function getJsonProveedores() {
        var items = "";
        $('input[type=radio][name=editList]').change(function () {
            if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")", function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                });
            }
            else if (this.value == 'Sucursal') {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUnidades", "Agenda")", function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Nombre + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                });

            } else if (this.value == 'Usuario') {
                $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUsuario", "Agenda")", function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.Nombre + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

It load correctly all JSON, but I have an issue removing last query, for example if i click `Proveedor` radio, it load:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")"
```

and next if I click Sucursal radio, it load

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUnidades", "Agenda")"
```

The problem is I keep seeing first query result of

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")"
```

instead getting only second one:

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetUnidades", "Agenda")"
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult GetProveedores()
        {
            var listaProveedores = db.Proveedores.ToList();
            return Json(listaProveedores, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult GetUnidades()
        {
            var listaUnidades = db.Unidades.ToList();
            return Json(listaUnidades, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult GetUsuario()
        {
            var listaUsuarios = db.Usuarios.ToList();
            return Json(listaUsuarios, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

What can be the problem there? Regards

Comment: what is the call you are making to this function?

Comment: Do you mean that each subsequent call is *appending* "items" instead of *replacing* them?

Comment: its only a json into controller: like return `Json(listaProveedores, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. I upload my controller to my question @Keith

Comment: Yes that´s exacly happens @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the functions/variables are structured, `items` never falls out of scope.  So it never gets reset.  Each subsequent AJAX call is simply *appending* to it.

Instead, get rid of the `items` variable from its current scope and use one local to each scope where you need it:

```
$(function getJsonProveedores() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=editList]').change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Proveedor') {
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetProveedores", "Agenda")", function (data) {
                var items = "";  // <--- declare it here
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    items += "<option value='" + item.ID + "'>" + item.NombreComercial + "</option>";
                });
                $("#lstProveedor").html(items);
            });
        }
        else if (this.value == 'Sucursal') {
        // ... and so on, declaring an "items" in each scope where you need it
```